# Rails: after_destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Scenario: I upload a attachment to a post form but then exit the post form before saving (#create).** (uploading directly to s3)

If I delete a post, then I can use `after_destroy` to delete the item within the post. But what if I simply exit the form before submitting. How can I get that item deleted without creating a 'temp bucket'?

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are not uploaded when you select them in the client; they are only uploaded when you submit the form. There shouldn't be anything to destroy.

If you are somehow doing the attachment upload before the submission takes place, you should be uploading them to tempfiles while will be swept periodically. When a form is saved, the uploaded files should be copied from the uploaded tempfiles into a more permanent location.

Comment: Sorry, I should've gave more info. I'm uploading directly to s3 so that my rails app won't ever be held up when uploading big files @Chris

Comment: Same advice applies. Upload to a temporary bucket, move files out of the temp bucket when the form is saved, flush old files from the temp bucket periodically. You'll have to be responsible for cleaning up the leftovers yourself.

Comment: Your missing the point. The reason why I'm uploading directly to s3 is because I will be uploading **very big files**. My server has limited bandwidth/disk space. So that, along with potential security issues, is the reason why I would like for my files to be uploaded directly to s3 & never have to touch my server @Chris

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not clear. You can still use S3, you just have to be responsible for cleaning up the files that get uploaded and not used. The easiest way to do this is to initially upload them to a temp S3 bucket, move them away when you save your form, and periodically (cron job, whatever) clean up anything in the temp bucket that is more than a certain age old.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Sorry. You're saying make a temp BUCKET. Seems like a lot more research & coding. I'm still new to rails btw.. No easier way, huh? @Chris